# Error in responsive menu loading (Wordpress Website)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing a website in `Wordpress` using a Child-theme. The question is that when I open a new tab in the browser or close it and open it again, one of the menus in the header appears duplicated when I work in responsive mode `(<1025 px)`, that is, it appears in the drop-down menu of the responsive menu aligned vertical and horizontal shape. It's strange, because when I reload the page (F5), this duplicity disappears and the vertical menu shows alone. This duplicity is also eliminated at the moment I click on another link to go to a sub-page.

In addition, and I understand the following is related to the above, when the web is on responsive mode and changes to the normal size (> 1024 px), if I come back to the responsive mode, the responsive menu appears in blank even if it is loaded (since I watch it in Chrome devtool). The css code that has associated indicates => "display: none", but when I reload the page, the css code shown is "display: block" , but it does not come from the theme style sheets; it appears as "user agent `stylesheet`". Why does the display value change when I reload the page?

Furthermore, with all this one, I performed test with the browsers Chrome and Firefox and deleting the cache and cookies and the problem is the same.

I would like that the responsive menu does not appears in blank or duplicated when I open a new tab in the browsers or switch from responsive size to the normal mode `(>1024px)`.

Below you can see the code into my header.php:

```
<nav id="MenuNav" class="navbar" style="display: inherit;">
<div id="menu" class="main-navigation ">
<ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="nav navbar-nav">
<li id="menu-item-739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type             
menu-item-object-page menu-item-739">
<a href="http://localhost/Cover/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-740" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type             
menu-item-object-page menu-item-740">
<a href="http://localhost/Cover/events/">Events</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-741" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type             
menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item         
page-item-39 current_page_item menu-item-741">
<a href="http://localhost/Cover/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

The css style beloging to the tag:

```
<nav id="MenuNav" class="navbar" style="display: inherit;">
```

is the following:

element.style {display: inherit;}. This css property come from the file footer.php and the following code lines:

foother.php:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
function msmenu(){
var wi = jQuery(window).width();
var nb = jQuery(".cloned").length;
if(wi <= '1024') {
if(nb < 1) {
jQuery("#MenuNav").clone().insertBefore("#page").addClass("cloned");
jQuery("#MenuNav").find('.navbar-nav').removeClass('navbar-nav');
jQuery("html").addClass('Mobinav');
}
}else{
if(jQuery('html').hasClass('Mobinav')){
jQuery('#MenuNav').remove();
jQuery('html').removeClass('navOpen').removeClass('Mobinav');
}
}
}
msmenu();
jQuery(window).resize(function() { msmenu(); });

jQuery('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){
jQuery('#MenuNav').toggleClass("open");
jQuery('html').toggleClass("navOpen");
});

jQuery(".navbar-toggle").toggle( function() {
jQuery('#MenuNav').css({ 'display' : 'block'});
}, function () {
jQuery('#MenuNav').css({ 'display' : 'inherit'});
});
jQuery('#search-toggle').click(function(){
jQuery('.bottom-header .searchbar').slideToggle(180);
});
});
new cbpScroller( document.getElementById( 'cbp-so-scroller' ) );
```

As you see, the css property above shown [element.style {display: inherit;}] comes from the line in footer.php: jQuery('#MenuNav').css({ 'display' : 'inherit'}); I modified this line to "display:inherit", because in footer.php was as "display:none", firstly. I do not know why when I change this css property, the style taken is shown as [element.style {display: inherit;}]  in Chrome DevTool and not is shown  as it comes from footer.php file.
Additionally, wether I set up the css property in footer.php as display: none, the responsive menu is not shown is my website (in blank). For this reason I have to change it but when I do it the menu appears duplicated as I mentioned above.

Kind regards.

Comment: Can you show the code or provide the Url of your site?

Comment: @Prabin Sapal, I edited my question, including the code and more explanation about my problem.